# What is the function of this Vue "dispatch"?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I have this existing working VueJs code

```
const actions = {
  retrieveStatus({ rootState, commit, dispatch }) {
    return Axios
      .get('/abc/GetStatus', {
        params: {
          draftId: rootState.eform.Id
        }
      })
      .then(response => {
        commit('SET_STATUS', response.data.statusCode);

        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        throw new Error('Errors');
      })
  },
```

I don't see anywhere it uses `dispatch` but it exists there.

Comment: `dispatch` is used for invoking actions in the store, here that argument is unused and is safe to remove. While you are at it, that `throw` statement in catch function is equally useless, you might want to clean that up as well.

Comment: oh, it has more descriptive error message but I removed it for brevity.

Comment: retrieveStatus is a callback, it receives any params that a caller (the store here) provides to it. Here the param is store context object. It exists regardless of whether you use it or not. You could remove  dispatch from destructured properties but then you'd need to write it again when you need it in this action or another one that is pasted from this one.